# Does Chromecast support PlayReady with WMV container format?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, wmv, playready

We would like to implement VOD streaming service with DRM protected stream.
Does Chromecast support PlayReady with WMV container format?
We have made PlayReady-encrypted files already. And we used wmv codec for video, and wma codec for audio and stored in wmv container.

There're some documents that chromecast can support Playready with PIFF format or CIF format etc. (Do Netflix and Hulu use PlayReady?)

I want to ask a question if chromecast support Playready DRM with WMV container format with wmv video and wma audio or not.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

WMV/WMA are not currently supported by Chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

No, Chromecast don't support WMV encrypted, you need to switch to SmoothStreaming using .ism/Manifest files.